# Can I select the size attribute for twitter bootstrap multiple select?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The size attribute doesn't seem to be working with Twitter bootstraps css file.  Am I missing something?

```
<div class="control-group"> 
    <div class="controls" >
        <select class="span2" multiple="multiple" id="multiSelect" size="2">
            <option>Assigned1</option>
            <option>Assigned2</option>
            <option>Assigned3</option>
            <option>Assigned4</option>
            <option>Assigned5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm works fine by me, what part is 'not working' and which browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/aAavj/

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  I see the default size of 4 every time.  Let me try a different browser.

Comment: strange. It works in IE but not Chrome

Comment: This is a know bug. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/z4rBqNT3174

Comment: They suggest setting a height with css, which is a bit ugly but will probably work.

Comment: The css worked...hokey but it works, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It should be working. I think you forgot a class from the container div.

```
<div class="control-group select optional">
    <label class="select optional control-label"> *Category</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="name" id="id" class="select optional" size="2">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this example and check how it works out. that's the way i'm using.

Comment: Arthur's solution worked for me on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dksmiffs/NR74p/).